# git push is stuck when pushing to remote

Tags: git

When I try to push to a remote repository,

`git push origin xyz`

it gets stuck. I try `ssh -T git@github.com` and I get a success:

> You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
>   provide shell access.

When I use the verbose option, I get a message that it is pushing:

`git push -v origin xyz`

> Pushing to git@github.com:repo.git

and it times out after about 10 minutes with another message:

> Connection to github.com closed by remote host.

And I do not get the prompt back in the shell.

I have tried the following but to no avail:

- including the `--dry-run` switch with `push` results the same.
- `git clean -d -f -i` followd by `git gc --auto`

I am on macOS High Sierra and using SSH authentication.

Comment: Remember, you can cancel a command to get control back. `ctrl + c`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turned out it was stuck due to a pre-push commit hook which was placed there (at `<repository-root>/.git/hooks/pre-push`) by a third-party tool.

To debug, I ran the command with `GIT_TRACE` on:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push -v origin xyz
11:47:11.950226 git.c:340               trace: built-in: git 'push' '-v' 'origin' ‘xyz’
Pushing to git@github.com:repo.git
11:47:11.951795 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@github.com' 'git-receive-pack ‘\’’repo.git'\'''
11:47:13.100323 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: '.git/hooks/pre-push' 'origin' 'git@repo.git'
```

Deleting the `pre-push` file solved the problem.

Comment: worked without deleting anything, but just adding GIT_TRACE=1!